# PHP string replacement operations with DB in consideration

Tags: php, database, string, preg-replace

I want to do some replacement type of operations on my string in PHP using DB.
For example:

```
$inputString = "My name is [[name-abc]] and age [[age-25]]";
```

And I have DB table as follow:

```
id    input        output
 1     name-abc    LINK_TO_ABC_PROFILE
 2     name-def    LINK_TO_DEF_PROFILE
 3     age-18      LINK_TO_AGE_18
 4     age-25      LINK_TO_AGE_25
```

And I need output:

```
$outputString = "My name is LINK_TO_ABC_PROFILE and age LINK_TO_AGE_25";
```

I tried various things with preg_replace but did not get the result. Can anybody write the function for me assuming DB is in my array as follows:

```
array('name-abc' => LINK_TO_ABC_PROFILE, 'name-def' => LINK_TO_DEF_PROFILE .... 'age-25' => LINK_TO_AGE_25)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$inputString = "My name is [[name-abc]] and age [[age-25]]";
$replace = array('name-abc' => LINK_TO_ABC_PROFILE, 'name-def' => LINK_TO_DEF_PROFILE , 'age-25' => LINK_TO_AGE_25);
$keys = array();
foreach ($replace as $k => $v) {
    $keys[] = '[[' . $k . ']]';
}
$out = str_replace ( $keys ,  array_values($replace) , $inputString );

var_dump(($out));
```

Output:

```
string(53) "My name is LINK_TO_ABC_PROFILE and age LINK_TO_AGE_25"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$details = array('name-abc' => LINK_TO_ABC_PROFILE, 'name-def' => LINK_TO_DEF_PROFILE .... 'age-25' => LINK_TO_AGE_25);

$outputString = "My name is ".$details['name-abc']." and age ".$details['age-25'];
?>
```

Comment: Hey man common, I dont know where that sub string "[[name-abc]]" is going to occur in my main input string..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use preg_replace, you have to frame two single dimensional array instead of associate array, try as follows,

```
$input_arr = array();
$output_arr = array();
$query = "SELECT input,output FROM replacestrtbl";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

if($stmt){
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($input, $output);
  $i=0;
  while($res = $stmt->fetch()){
  $input_arr[$i] = '/\[\['.$input.'\]\]/';
  $output_arr[$i] = $output;
  $i++;
  }
  $stmt->close();
}

$inputString = "My name is [[name-abc]] and age [[age-25]]";

$output_string=preg_replace($input_arr,$output_arr,$inputString);

echo $output_string;
```